# How to first order files in folder by date and then concatenate their contents into a new file?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, merge

I have a folder with four to five text files in it.

My overall aim is the following: Create one big file which has the content of the separate files, but in the right order.

I can use the time-stamp of each file to start with the oldest file up to the youngest.

My process right now looks like this:

1. Order the files in this folder by date.
2. Create a temporary file and write the content from the separate files into this file.
3. Output the temporary file.

In code I do something like this:

```
set temp_concat=%temp_dir%\temp_concat.log
echo %temp_concat%
echo aiu_logs   > %temp_concat%
for /f "delims=" %%? in ('dir /b /o:d %Folder%*') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%K in (%Folder%%%?) do (
        echo  %%K   >>%temp_concat%
    )
)
```

The above code seems to work as my `temp_concat` is very large.

However, this takes much much longer than expected. I have to wait about 40 seconds just to merge three files in my case.

Is there some better way of merging some amount of files, but keep them in the correct order by date?

Comment: I am a bit confused on why you have nested `FOR` commands.  Should only need one `FOR` command. Then use the `TYPE` command to output the file. Also the `FOLDER` variable is not defined.  If it is only a few files then I would create a single variable from the `FOR` command with all the files it is finding.  Then use the COPY command to concatenate them together.

Comment: Thanks @squashman, i used your tip with Type, i Post my used solution when i am back home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch file uses the suggestion posted by [Sqashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) to use a **FOR** loop to create the arguments string for command **COPY** used to concatenate the file contents into a single file in the order of oldest modified file first and newest modified file last.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Folder=%~dp0"
if not "%~1" == "" set "Folder=%~1"
set "Folder=%Folder:/=\%"
if not "%Folder:~-1%" == "\" set "Folder=%Folder%\"

set "ResultsFile=%Folder%Results.log"
del "%ResultsFile%" 2>nul
set "Arguments="

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D-H /B /O:D "%Folder%*" 2^>nul') do if not "%%~fI" == "%~f0" set "Arguments=!Arguments! + "%%I""

if defined Arguments (
    echo aiu_logs>"%ResultsFile%"
    copy /B "%ResultsFile%"%Arguments% "%ResultsFile%" >nul
)

endlocal
```

The batch file as is does not work if either the folder path or one of the file names contains one or more exclamation marks `!` because of an enabled [delayed environment variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Further the command line length is limited and so this batch file does not work on too many files must be concatenated depending on length of the file path of each file and the length of the file names.

A better solution would be using following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "Folder=%~dp0"
if not "%~1" == "" set "Folder=%~1"
set "Folder=%Folder:/=\%"

pushd "%Folder%" 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto EndBatch

set "ResultsFile=Results.log"
del "%ResultsFile%" 2>nul
set "Arguments="

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D-H /B /O:D * 2^>nul') do if not "%%~fI" == "%~f0" call set "Arguments=%%Arguments%% + "%%I""

if defined Arguments (
    echo aiu_logs>"%ResultsFile%"
    copy /B "%ResultsFile%"%Arguments% "%ResultsFile%" >nul
)

popd
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

A folder path with one or more exclamation marks is no problem anymore. Also the file names can contain `!` because of delayed expansion is not used by this batch file which is a bit slower than the first batch file.

The folder with the files to concatenate is made the current directory by this batch file. For that reason more file names can be specified as arguments on **COPY** command line in comparison to first batch file because of the file names are specified without path. But the number of file contents which can be merged with this batch file is nevertheless limited by the maximum length of a Windows command line respectively the maximum length of an environment variable value.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `copy /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>` and `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the **DIR** command line between the two `'` appended as further arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The second `FOR /F` does not contain a command. It contains a filename. I have not tested this, but perhaps:

```
set temp_concat=%temp_dir%\temp_concat.log
echo %temp_concat%
echo aiu_logs   > "%temp_concat%"
for /f "delims=" %%? in ('dir /b /o:d "%Folder%"') do (
    if not "%%~f?" == "%~f0" (
        type %%? >>"%temp_concat%"
    )
)
```

This will concatenate all files in the "%Folder%" directory. Paths should be quoted in case there are special characters in them.